# Elasticsearch and Java Spring Boot : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

So I am trying to get my Spring Boot webservice to talk to Elasticsearch (I have another Java app that works)

The error I am getting is

> DependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'searchController':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'searchService'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'searchService': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'searchRepository'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'searchRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.mapping.put.PutMappingRequestBuilder.execute()Lorg/elasticsearch/action/ListenableActionFuture;
>   2018-10-27 22:18:49.139  INFO 1925 --- [           main]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]

My dependencies (Gradle) are

```
compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.plugin', name: 'transport-netty4-client', version: '6.4.2'
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'transport', version: '6.4.2'
    compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:6.4.2'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch')
```

My model

```
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "burf", type = "pages")
data class Result(@Id val handle: String,
                  val url: String,
                  val title: String,
                  val body: String,
                  val meta_description: String?) {

}
```

Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = arrayOf("com.burfdevelopment.skynet.repository\n"))
@ComponentScan(basePackages = arrayOf("com.burfdevelopment.skynet.service"))
class Config {

    @Value("\${elasticsearch.home:/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch}")
    private val elasticsearchHome: String? = null

    @Value("\${elasticsearch.cluster.name:skynet}")
    private val clusterName: String? = null

    @Bean
    fun client(): Client {
        val settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", clusterName).build()

        return PreBuiltTransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.100"), 9300))
    }

    @Bean
    fun elasticsearchTemplate(): ElasticsearchOperations {
        return ElasticsearchTemplate(client())
    }
}
```

Repository

```
interface SearchRepository : ElasticsearchRepository<Result, String>  {

    fun findByTitle(name: String, pageable: Pageable): Page<Result>
}
```

Anyone got any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version of Spring Boot that you are using uses a version of Spring Data Elasticsearch that isn’t compatible with Elasticsearch 6.4.

To ensure that you use compatible versions, remove the version from your Elasticsearch dependencies and allow Spring Boot’s dependency management to control the version instead.

Comment: So which lines should I remove? Do I need to downgrade my server?

Comment: You should remove the versions from the dependencies declared in your `build.gradle`. I don’t know what versions of the Elasticsearch client are compatible with which versions of the server. Its documentation may have some information on that.

Comment: I can't describe how useful this thread was.  This should be the number one search result on Google for NoSuchMethodError elasticsearch spring boot.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson This would only work if the elasticsearch version is 6.8 or below. For those who want to make it to work for Elasticsearch version 7.0 which is not supported yet officially.

Answer (score 1):

For those who trying with 7.0, it's not yet supported on the Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Refer to the below link for elastic search versions supported.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions

**Alternate Approach** : Use RestHighLevelClient and LowLevelClients to interact. The features of JPA will be missing.